# Random Number 01-99 MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following Id for my table:

```
SELECT CONCAT('TPR-', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d-%h-%m-%s')) AS Id;
```

At the End, I want to add a random number start from `01-99`. How can I achieve this?

I tried the following syntax, but I want to add leading zero if the number is start from 1 - 9.

```
FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) * 99 )
```

Need advice please.

Answer (score 1):

Just  use the LPAD function: `LPAD( FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) * 99 ), 2, '0')`

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-lpad-function.php